# Not able to serialize a model object in django signals

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Task model. After saving the task I want to send a FCM to a device. So I decided to use django signals. Here's the code for it:

The model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    issuer = models.ForeignKey(EndUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='history')
    assignee = models.ForeignKey(Mechanic, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='history')
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='history')
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField('Task Status', choices=TASK_STATUS, default=TASK_STATUS[0][0], max_length=64)
    payment_status = models.CharField('Payment Status', choices=PAYMENT_STATUS,
                                      default=PAYMENT_STATUS[0][0], max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}-{}-{}".format(self.service, self.issuer, self.assignee)


post_save.connect(send_mechanic_notification, sender=Task)
```

The signal function:

```
def send_mechanic_notification(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.assignee.device.send_message(
            title='New Task Available!',
            body='Hey!! A new task is available for you',
            data={
                "event": "new_task",
                "data": instance
            }
        )
```

Now, obviously this won't work because instance is a model object and needs to be serialized. So I tried using a serializer that I have defined. But this was causing circular dependency.

I don't want to user model_to_dict because it doesn't serialize the nested fields, and serializing the nested fields is a requirement.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

import the serializer ***locally*** (inside your function)

```
def send_mechanic_notification(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    
    from somewhere.serializer import MySerializer
    
    if created:
        instance.assignee.device.send_message(
            title='New Task Available!',
            body='Hey!! A new task is available for you',
            data={
                "event": "new_task",
                "data": instance
            }
        )
```

Comment: Thanks it worked....I'm laughing at myself right now lol.

Comment: Glad that worked!!! Please do accept the answer and hit the Upvote button :)

Comment: You're importing MySerializer, but you're not using it for anything so I don't understand your solution.